# Open directory from variable with spaces in shell

Tags: bash, shell, variables, ksh, cd

I have name of directory `New folder` in variable `i`. I know this directory exist in my current path but when my shell script try to open it with `cd \"$i\"` i get a message: `No such file or directory: "New folder"`. But if I enter name directly `cd "New folder"` - it works. Why it's not working with variable?

Thank you

Comment: Don't escape the quotes.... ` i="New Folder"; cd "$i"`

Comment: You are running the script  from the same folder?

Comment: Does it work when you type `cd \"New folder\"`?  Why are you testing a different string?

Comment: I don't know the name `New folder`. Its in the variable in script. Yes. `New folder` and script are in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. It simply works when `i="New folder"` for `cd "$i"`